# An IMO 1984 longlisted problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Below is a longlisted problem of IMO 1984 which I got stuck on:

Consider all the sums of the form

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1985}e_{k}k^5 = \pm1^5 \pm2^5 \pm ... \pm 1985^5 $$

where $e_{k} = \pm1$, what is the smallest nonnegative value of the sum attained by a sum of this form?

I have been thinking about this problem for a while now. One thing comes to my mind immediately after I saw this problem was that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}e_{k}k^2$ covers the set of integers because $$(n-1)^2-n^2-(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2=4$$ and $1=1^2,2=-1^2-2^2-3^2+4^2,3=-1^2+2^2$. So if the problem were about squares, we know the answer is $1$ since $1984/4=496$ and we can pair the terms after 1 into $248$ paires of $\pm4$.

On the other hand, I don't believe there are such nice identities for powers greater than $2$. So how should I proceed with the original question? Any hint or thought is appreciated.

Comment: Such identities exist, just highly impractical: $k^5-(k+1)^5-(k+2)^5+(k+3)^5-(k+4)^5+(k+5)^5+(k+6)^5-(k+7)^5-(k+8)^5+(k+9)^5+(k+10)^5-(k+11)^5+(k+12)^5-(k+13)^5-(k+14)^5+(k+15)^5-(k+16)^5+(k+17)^5+(k+18)^5-(k+19)^5+(k+20)^5-(k+21)^5-(k+22)^5+(k+23)^5+(k+24)^5-(k+25)^5-(k+26)^5+(k+27)^5-(k+28)^5+(k+29)^5+(k+30)^5-(k+31)^5=-122880$

Comment: It does mean that there a combination of $k^5,\dots,(k+63)^5$ which is $0$.

Comment: Actually, since $1985\equiv1\pmod{64}$, this means $1$ is realizable.

Comment: @KentaS Thanks for the reply! It is very nice to see such an identity! However I think since $1984/64=31$ which is odd, this only means that $122879$ is realizable?

Comment: Note that the original identity I posted uses 32 terms.

Comment: @KentaS Also I am very curious: if you don't mind sharing, how do you get such identities?

Comment: @KentaS Ah you are right! would you like to write an answer so I can credit you?

Comment: It would have been amazing if someone answered that problem with one such sum adding up to 1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, given a polynomial $p$ of degree $k$, the difference $p(x+a)-p(x)$ has degree $<k$, for any constant $a$. Thus, we see that:

\begin{align*}
p_1(n):=(n+1)^5-n^5 &\text{ has degree }\le 4 \\
p_2(n):=p_1(n+2)-p_1(n)=(n+3)^5-(n+2)^5-(n+1)^5+n^5 &\text{ has degree }\le 3 \\
p_3(n):=p_2(n+4)-p_2(n) &\text{ has degree }\le 2 \\
p_4(n):=p_3(n+8)-p_3(n) &\text{ has degree }\le 1\\
p_5(n):=p_3(n+16)-p_3(n) &\text{ has degree }\le 0,\text{ i.e., is constant}\\
p_6(n)=p_5(n+32)-p_5(n)=0.
\end{align*}
Thus, there is an expression of the form $\pm n^5\pm\cdots\pm(n+63)^5=0$. Since $1985\equiv1\pmod{64}$, this shows $1$ is realizable as $\sum_{k=1}^{1985}e_kk^5$ by choosing $e_k$ periodically for $k>1$.

To finish, note that $0$ is not achievable by parity.

Comment: The sign of $e_k$ depends of the number of $1$s in the binary representation of $k$. If this number is odd, choose $e_k=-1$, if it is even, then $e_k=+1$ .The other way round will work, too.

Comment: Right, its the so-called Thue-Morse sequence.